# Updating a variable across functions

Tags: python-3.x, function, file

I've got to use my login() Function, then my gameswon() function, then the login function. The first use of login, variable player should ==1, then the gameswon function will set player==2 for the login system to use. But on the second use of login() it still thinks player==1.

Ive tried using global player, Ive also tried using an external file, neither has worked.

Login Function:

```
def login():
    global player
    player="1"
    loop="incorrect"
    global p1username
    global p2username
    if player=="1":
        p1username=0
        p2username=1
    if player=="2":
        p2username=1
    username=0                                                                                   
    password=0                                                                                  
    open("dice_scores.txt","a")                                                                       
    file=open("users.txt","a")                                                                      
    while loop==("incorrect"):                                                                
        accq=input("Player "+player+" do you have an account? ")                                     
        if accq=="ADMIN":                                                                
            admin=open("users.txt","r")                                                        
            filecontents = admin.read()                                                      
            print(filecontents)                                                            
        if accq=="yes":                                                                       
                open("users.txt")                                                      
                userbase=open("users.txt")                                            
                username=input("Input username: ")                                                
                password=input("Input password: ")                                    
                if player==str(1):
                    p1username=username
                elif player==str(2):
                    p2username=username
                combinedup=(username+"."+password+",")                                       
                with open("users.txt") as x:                                                      
                    if username==1 or username==0:
                        print("Username cannot be 1 or 0")
                        loop=("incorrect")
                    if p2username==p1username:                                        
                        print("User already logged in, please try again.")                   
                        loop=("incorrect")
                    else:
                        if combinedup in x.read():                                                   
                            loop=("correct")                                  
                            print("Correct Details","\n")                                             
                        else:                                                                       
                            print("Incorrect Details")                                  
                            loop=("incorrect")                            
        if accq=="no":                                                   
            userbase=open("users.txt","a")               
            accexist="exists"                                                         
            while accexist=="exists":                                                 
                createusername=input("Create username: ")                                       
                createpassword=input("Create password: ")                        
                combinedup=(createusername+"."+createpassword+",")             
                with open("users.txt") as x:                                                   
                    if createusername+"." in x.read():                                   
                        print("Username already exists try again")                        
                        accexist=("exists")                                    
                    else:                                                                
                        accexist=("valid")                                            
            userbase.write(combinedup + "\n")                                 
            print("Account created successfully! Return to login")     
            loop=("incorrect")                                    
            userbase.close()                                     
    accq=0
    username=0       
    password=0
    loop="incorrect"
```

Gameswon function:

```
    global player

    global p1gameswon
    global p1gameslost
    global p2gameswon
    global p2gameslost
    p1gameswon=0                                                                                 
    p1gameslost=0                                                                         
    p2gameswon=0                                                    
    p2gameslost=0                                                                
    file=open("dice_scores.txt","r")                                         

    if player=="2":
        for gameswon in file:                                                              
            if (p2username) in gameswon and ("GAME WON!") in gameswon:              
                p2gameswon=p2gameswon+1                                                          

        file=open("dice_scores.txt","r")                                                            
        for gameslost in file:                                                              
            if (p2username) in gameslost and ("GAME LOST!") in gameslost:            
                p2gameslost=p2gameslost+1                                                   
        print("Welcome",p2username,"you have won",p2gameswon,"games and lost",p2gameslost,"games!","\n")

    if player=="1":
        for gameswon in file:                                                             
            if (p1username) in gameswon and ("GAME WON!") in gameswon:            
                p1gameswon=p1gameswon+1                                                   

        file=open("dice_scores.txt","r")                                          
        for gameslost in file:                                                            
            if (p1username) in gameslost and ("GAME LOST!") in gameslost:  
                p1gameslost=p1gameslost+1                                             
        print("Welcome",p1username,"you have won",p1gameswon,"games and lost",p1gameslost,"games!","\n")
        playerfile=open("player.txt","w")
        player=playerfile.write(str("2"))
        player="2"
        print("DONE")
    file.close()
```

Comment: That is because at the beginning of your `login` function you set `player = '1'`.

Comment: Declare the global outside of the function and set it to '1' outside as well :o)

Comment: Also consider using arrays for your player information so that you don't need to repeat your code in the GamesWon function. You could have a playerIndex (0 or 1) that accesses the other information in an array. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/array.